# No me actualiza con Update

Tags: c#, sql, windows-forms, update

Estoy intentando modificar una contraseña en función de un textbox. Pasa el código pero no me actualiza la base de datos.

```
                string conexion = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Resources\\Atreus_bbdd.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conexion))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    string update = "UPDATE Users SET [Password]= @pass WHERE [Usuario]= @user AND [DNI]= @dni AND [Email]= @Email";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(update, con);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", tb_usuario.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dni", tb_dni.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", tb_email.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", tb_pass1.Text);
                    con.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("Contraseña modificada por: ' " + tb_pass1.Text + " '", "Atreus - Modificado", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
                this.Hide();
                Login.main_login form = new Login.main_login();
                form.Show();
```

Espero que me podais hechar una mano.

Gracias de antemanos

Comment: Te aconsejo que emplees Entity Framework, te facilitaría mucho la vida.

Comment: En ese código no estas ejecutando la query, la creas pero no ejecutas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te dije en el comentario te falta ejecutar la query.
Te dejo el código:

```
 string conexion = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Resources\\Atreus_bbdd.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conexion))
            {
                con.Open();
                string update = "UPDATE Users SET [Password]= @pass WHERE [Usuario]= @user AND [DNI]= @dni AND [Email]= @Email";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(update, con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", tb_usuario.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dni", tb_dni.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", tb_email.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", tb_pass1.Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // Esta linea es la que te falta en tu código
                con.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Contraseña modificada por: ' " + tb_pass1.Text + " '", "Atreus - Modificado", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            this.Hide();
            Login.main_login form = new Login.main_login();
            form.Show();
```

Un saludo.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!